# What are the validations underneath when we apply DataType.Password on a field in MVC 4 model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, passwords, data-annotations

I am planning to display a message to the user to assist them entering a correct password before they actually start typing in a password while registering on site. This is to avoid user frustration.

I have applied "DataType.Password" annotation on the related field in my MVC model. I tried to google to find a guide mentioning what's allowed in Password, but couldn't find much details.

Anyone having an idea of Password criteria when this attribute is applied?

Any help on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no validation rules associated with `DataType.Password`.  You will have to add your own validation attributes.

Comment: yes, I realized the validation rules might be on @Html.PasswordFor which is being used to associate this field on the view.